# NDVI calculation in GeoServer using Rendering Transformations

Tags: geoserver

I want to publish an NDVi layer of an image with GeoServer and I found there is a function called Rendering Transformations in GeoServer that allows rendering NDVI from the original image. When I followed the instruction on the section *Running map algebra on the fly using Jiffle* of [this page](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html), I got an NDVI layer published. However, I found the NDVI result in every cell is wrong and does not match the result I calculated with Raster Calculator of ArcMap as is shown below.

[image: The result from ArcGIS]
The result from ArcGIS

[image: The result from Geoserver]
The result from Geoserver

I am using GeoServer 2.20.1 and ArcGIS 10.8 on Windows 10. The original data is a 16 bit float image,which contains 4 bands(r,g,b,nir). The style I used is as follows. Why did this happen? How can I get the right NDVI?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.0.0">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>NDVI</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>NDVI</Title>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Transformation>
                    <ogc:Function name="ras:Jiffle">
                        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                            <ogc:Literal>coverage</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                            <ogc:Literal>script</ogc:Literal>
                            <ogc:Literal>
                                nir = src[3];
                                vir = src[0];
                                if (nir != 65535.0){
                                    dest = (nir - vir) / (nir + vir);
                                 } else {
                                    dest = 2.0;
                                 }
                            </ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                    </ogc:Function>
                </Transformation>
                <Rule>
                    <RasterSymbolizer>
                        <ColorMap>
                            <ColorMapEntry color="#000000" quantity="-1"/>
                            <ColorMapEntry color="#0000ff" quantity="-0.75"/>
                            <ColorMapEntry color="#ff00ff" quantity="-0.25"/>
                            <ColorMapEntry color="#ff0000" quantity="0"/>
                            <ColorMapEntry color="#ffff00" quantity="0.5"/>
                            <ColorMapEntry color="#00ff00" quantity="1"/>
                            <ColorMapEntry color="#ffffff" quantity="2" opacity="0"/>
                        </ColorMap>
                    </RasterSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

And this is how I use Raster Calculator of ArcMap.
[image]

---

Update

Aspired by the comments from @Andrea Aime, I exported the vir value and nir value.
The main part of the GeoServer style for test is like this

```
nir = src[3];
vir = src[0];
dest[0] = vir;
dest[1] = nir;
dest[2] = (nir - vir)/(nir + vir);
```

The results are as follows
[image: The result from ArcGIS]
The result from ArcGIS

[image: The result from GeoServer]
The result from GeoServer

There seems to be some problems in reading values from the nir band of the original image and I don't know why.(Maybe it's caused by the pixel depth limit?)

Some other examples:
[image: example1]
[image: example2]

Comment: how are you calculating the NDVI in arc? are you sure that you have the bands correct in your calculation?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am sure the bands are used correctly both in ArcGIS and Geoserver. I will add the calculation information of arcGIS soon.

Comment: At the level of zoom you're using, it's difficult to tell if you're really clicking on the same pixel. Best zoom so that pixels are visibly oversampled, and then click in the resulting "big square". Also, you can bring out also the values used for calculation if your GeoServer is recent enough, using dest[0], dest[1], dest[2] and so on. See: http://geoserver.org/announcements/2020/09/26/geoserver-2-18-0-released.html

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Actually, the ndvi range of the whole area is about 0.6~0.7 in ArcGIS but only 0.12~0.16 in GeoServer. I will also try to export red chanel and nir channel and check the values.

Comment: It's as if the data in ArcGIS was linearly stretched on band4, while GeoServer is likely reading the original pixel values?

Comment: I am afraid not. It is proved that ArcGIS can show both the pixel value and stretched value for the all the layers. And I think the value (of bands and NDVI) from ArcGIS is more reasonable, because the NDVIs from GeoServer are all in the range from 0 to 0.3 (Usually the average NDVI of a healthy evergreen plant is around or above 0.6 according to my experience). And the values of trees' pixels is lower than that of sea's pixels. That's really strange.